# Not able to Open serial device, while running binary in Cygwin

Tags: cygwin

-i have created binary in Cygwin, and try to run that binary.
   -in such way, I'm trying to Open serial device, but not able to open that serial device getting Error **No such file or directory**.
   -I have use Same binary and run it on my other system and it is working fine.

Note- I have installed same Cygwin packages on both the system.

can anyone guide me, what should I have to do to prevent this issue.

Comment: for your reference,
Error while trying to open serial port:
**Couldn't open serial device "/dev/ttys55"(No such file or directory)**

Comment: ttys55 seems unusual. What it the windows name of the serial device?